# How does the Firebreath plugin run on Windows XP?

Tags: firebreath

Windows7 using VS2013 development of a plug-in, and perfect running on `ie8`, now transferred to Windows XP, ie8 browser **can not load** plug-ins.

**I take the measures:**

1. VS2013 on Windows 7, select the **v120_xp**, but there is **no effect**;
2. Install the **XP system**, **VS2010** in the virtual machine,Run Firebreath demo again,the following error occurred:

Can not open the program database "d: \ firebreath-master \ build \ npapicore \ npapicore.dir \ debug \ vc100.idb"

how can i do?`@taxilian`

Comment: `@taxilian` please help me！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not particularly appropriate to call out a specific person to answer a question on stackoverflow. I do monitor this tag, so I see it, but just so you are aware =]

There are three basic reasons why a plugin may not load:

1. The plugin is not registered correctly

   - This shouldn't be possible, since firebreath takes care of that for you; can't guarantee that nothing went wrong, of course. The only way to troubleshoot this is to learn how registration works and double check everything.
2. The plugin DLL has libraries which are not available on the system

   - This would be my #1 guess as to what is happening; the best way to check is to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what dependencies it has that may not be available; `ieshims.dll` is a common one to see looking like it isn't there when it works, but most anything else is likely to be a problem. It's quite possible that there are dependencies added by vs2013 that aren't there with vs2010; I'd also verify that the target set in win_common.h in firebreath is correct for windows XP.
3. The plugin may actually be loading but then crashing immediately.

   - The easiest way to test this would be to add a call to [__debugbreak()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) early in the plugin lifecycle; this will make it look like it crashed but let you attach a debugger.

If none of that helps I'd recommend using the [firebreath-dev](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/firebreath-dev) google group which is a more appropriate place for a discussion.

Comment: thank you very much! Your answer is a solution to my problem, but I have another problem.In the case of no change wsx, there "error 47 error LGHT0204: ICE38: Component cmp89D2F4E963FB530291488843FA376445 installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.
".

Comment: There is also a problem, used in the projectDef.cmake,target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} debug "${ROOT_PATH}/DevelopKit/libs/XXX.lib");target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} release "${ROOT_PATH}/DevelopKit/libs/XXX.lib"),VS2013 who Always automatically give me in the "connection -> input" add "release.lib",How should I do,thanks.

Comment: please don't ask another question in the comments. if you have a discussion, you might consider the firebreath-dev google group. Not only is it bad practice on stackoverflow but I can't tell what you're asking in an unformatted comment

Comment: Really very grateful, I found a lot of problems are dll missing reasons.Dependency Walker is very useful.cool.